# How to save a String list or integer list from spring boot to elasticsearch

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data

i just want to pass a list of integer/ list of string to save in my elasticsearch data store from my spring boot application. I am sending the request through postman but it gives following error.

```
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"message": "Elasticsearch exception [type=mapper_parsing_exception, reason=object mapping for [abPath] tried to parse field [null] as object, but found a concrete value]"
```

my model class **abPath** class variable is configured as follows

```
@Field( type = FieldType.Integer, store = true)
private List<Integer> abPath;
```

My Postman request attribute set as follows

```
"abPath": [1, 2, 3]
```

if i set "abPath" as null, request is completed without any errors

after that i found a way to save as follows

```
public class AB{
   private Integer abId;
   // constructor and getter setter
}

//then i update my model
@Field( type = FieldType.Nested)
private List<AB> abPath;

//then postman request updated as follows
"abPath" : [{"abId" : 1}, {"abId" : 2}]
```

then request completed without any errors..

I want to know is,

is that the way to save integer list or string list into elasticsearch?

is there any other better approaches?

can i save the list of integers or list of strings without wrapping values into any other objects like i did?

Comment: Can you post your mapping?

Comment: Can u post your mapping. And the call where you are saving im asuming you are using a Repository. could you post that too

Answer (score 1):

According to me, the way you have implemented is a good way. With this approach, we can even query on inner fields. I am also managing it in the same way.